Ladder logic for multi stage motor setup
I have three motors connected to a high pressure misting system. One motor is variable and is sized about 20% larger than the other two motors. They are on-off motors. All three motors work in tandem to keep the line pressurized at approximately 1000 psi. The way it should work is that the variable motor should try to maintain that pressure. If unable to do so when running at 100 % it should throttle down to about 20 % and kick on a second motor. If still unable to maintain that pressure while running at 100 % and 1 motor running, it should kick on the second motor, and repeat.
I'm looking for ladder logic, diagrams, tips, or pretty much anything to help me get started on this. I want to control all that with a BRX PLC using Do-More Designer software. Being under pressure for 5 seconds or so between stage changes shouldn't be an issue. I'd want to avoid any over pressure, or at least limit it to 200 psi over set point. Figure for a 2-second delay in VFD, I'm really unsure about that part.

What happens if the system is over-pressurised? What happens during under-pressure? What's the response time of the VFD? For how long can you tolerate an over / under-pressure? Please edit the information into the question - don't bury it in the comments.

Here are some ideas to get you going.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Pump speeds as a function of demand. (Ignore the arrows. It's the only way to draw sloping lines in CircuitLab.)
Pseudo code
                              // SP = pressure set point
If Pressure < SP - 40 for 1 s:   // 80 psi hysteresis
  Pump1_Speed += 10%             // Increase speed by 10%
  Reset timer                    // 10%/s
If Pressure > SP + 40 for 1 s:   // 80 psi hysteresis
  Pump1_Speed -= 10%             // Decrease speed by 10%
  Reset timer                    // 10%/s

if Pump1_Speed = 100% for 2 s:
    Oneshot Pump1_Speed = 10%
    Set Pump2
if Pressure > SP AND Pump1_Speed < 20%:
    Reset Pump2

if Pump2_Set AND Pump1_Speed = 100% for 2 s:
    Oneshot Pump1_Speed = 10%
    Set Pump3
if Pressure > SP AND Pump1_Speed < 20%:
    Reset Pump3


From the comments:

I'm running my ladder logic through a simulator before I apply it to real life.

That's a good idea. I would try modelling the system as an electrical analog.

simulate this circuit
Figure 2. Electrical equivalent of hydraulic system.

I'm assuming the pumps are consistent displacement per revolution. e.g., One revolution displaces a certain volume of fluid. This is represented by a current source in the schematic. The setpoint for the current is determined by the sum of displacements per unit time from the three pumps.
R1 represents the resistance to flow. It's variable.
VM1, a voltmeter, is analogous to the pressure.

For the simulation,

I1, I2 and I3 are the outputs of the three pumps. I1 will vary with the VFD. I2 and I3 will be zero when off and a constant value when on. Sum the three of them to get the total volume.
You might want to ramp the I values to model each pump start and stop.
Continuously calculate the pressure using Ohm's law.
If you have a HMI then bind a slider component to R1 so you can adjust it quickly and easily. Add indicators for the motor status and VFD speed. Add a pressure gauge.

This may seem like a lot of trouble but I'm sure it will allow you to do a lot of testing without risk of damage.

This seems pretty straightforward and I should have no issue convert that code into ladder logic. For the 2nd and 3rd stage I would want Pump 1 to instantly throttle down to 20%, otherwise it could result in a couple seconds of over pressure.

OK. I've added a one-shot in each case to set the variable pump to 10% at the same time the next pump is brought in. Have you got a means of testing this safely?

Ok, that should be all I need to go on, thanks! I'm running my ladder logic through a simulator before I apply it to real life. As far as testing it on the actual motors, I have to talk with the install guy for that. Unless there's something you'd recommend?

See the update.
